# Exponentiation closure of the positive rationals

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation, rational-numbers

It's a trivial fact that the natural numbers are colsed under exponentiation, i.e. x^y is natural for every couple of naturals x,y.

If I start from the positive rationals and add all powers iteratively, I definetly stay inside the positive reals. I think the resulting set contains the algebraic numbers but it is still countable. what else can be said about this set?

Is there some field in mathematics that generalize these questions?

Comment: What do you mean with “add all powers iteratively”?

Comment: If you have two numbers in the initial set, for example 3 and 1/2, then add to the set the number 3^(1/2) or square root of 3. You get then another set which contain the original. Now repeat this process and take the union of all the sets you get.

Comment: I don't think this contains the algebraic numbers since there are polynomial equations which aren't solvable by radicals.